# Evaluate str with Python

Tags: python, split, eval

I want to use the method `eval` in python to evaluate an expression. I know it works but the problem is that I have strings in the expression.
For example: `"CR*12+LA"`
where CR and LA are two code in a dictionary: `{'code':'CR','val':5},{'code':'LA','val':2}`
How can I pick the strings and search this value in dictionaries to evaluate the expression? I try to use the `split` method but I can't fix it. Can any one help me?

Comment: can you post your sample code / sample data

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `eval` at all as it's extremely dangerous. Can you post a code sample?